# Shopware 6 get products from product stream with currency and storefront language

Tags: shopware, shopware6

i have the following variables:

```php
$secretApiKey = $a->get('secretApiKey');
$publicApiKey = $a->get('publicApiKey');
$productStreamId = $a->get('productStreamId');
$salesChannelId = $a->get('salesChannelId');
$ruleId = $a->get('ruleId');
$currencyId = $a->get('currencyId');
```

how can i get the products from the product stream with the currency and the default language of the storefront given?

I have seen the following: https://github.com/shopware/core/blob/trunk/Content/Product/SalesChannel/CrossSelling/ProductCrossSellingRoute.php

But i dont have a context, cause the function can be executed by an command and scheduler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply construct the context yourself if you have all the necessary arguments.

```xml
<service id="SwagBasicExample\Command\ExampleCommand">
    <argument type="service" id="product.repository"/>
    <argument type="service" id="Shopware\Core\Content\ProductStream\Service\ProductStreamBuilder"/>
    <tag name="console.command"/>
</service>
```

```php
$context = new Context(
    new SystemSource(),
    [$ruleId],
    $currencyId,
    [$languageId, Defaults::LANGUAGE_SYSTEM]
);

$filters = $this->productStreamBuilder->buildFilters(
    $productStreamId,
    $context
);

$criteria = new Criteria();
$criteria->addFilter(...$filters);

$products = $this->productRepository->search($criteria, $context);
```

Alternatively you can inject `AbstractSalesChannelContextFactory` to build the entire `SalesChannelContext` and thus also the `Context` from only the id of the sales channel.

```xml
<argument type="service" id="Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\Context\SalesChannelContextFactory"/>
```

```php
// You can optionally override the options of the sales channel
// e.g. if a sales channel has multiple languages assigned
// and you want to use a language other than the default
$options = [
    SalesChannelContextService::LANGUAGE_ID => $languageId,
];

$salesChannelContext = $this->salesChannelContextFactory->create(
    Uuid::randomHex(),
    $salesChannelId,
    $options
);
$context = $salesChannelContext->getContext();
```